# How passing props to component (Dynamic Routing)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Please tell me how I can passing props to component (**Card**) in dynamic routing. I get array from JSON and put it to Redux.
Example JSON:

```
{
    "product": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "image": "/assets/images/products/27672/1.jpg",
            "name": "Product 1",
            "price": "0.20",
            "category": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "image": "/assets/images/products/27672/2.jpg",
            "name": "Product 2",
            "price": "0.1",
            "category": 3
        }
]
}
```

App component:

```
<div className="App">
  <Header />
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
    <Route path='/product/:id' element={<Card />} />
  </Routes>
  <Footer />
</div>
```

Link on product in Home component. Clicking on the link should take to product page. Id product from JSON.

```
<div className="catalog_block">
   <Link to={'product/' + id}>
     <img src={image} />
    </Link>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass props to `Card` like you would any other React component:

```
<Route path='/product/:id' element={<Card /* pass props here */ />} />
```

But what I really think you are asking for is how to use the `id` route path parameter to fetch a specific element from the `product` array. For this the `Card` component should use the `useParams` hook to access the `id` path parameter and then find the matching element from the `product` array.

Example:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Card = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const specificProduct = product.find(el => String(el.id) === id);

  ..

  if (!product) {
    // render no matching product JSX
  }

  return (
    // matching product JSX
  );
};
```

Alternatively you can pass the specific product in route state and access via the `useLocation` hook via `location.state`.

Example:

```
<Link
  to={'product/' + id}
  state={{ product: specificProductBeingIterated }}
>
  <img src={image} />
</Link>
```

...

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const Card = () => {
  const { state } = uselocation();
  const { product } = state || {};

  ..

  if (!product) {
    // render no matching product JSX
  }

  return (
    // matching product JSX
  );
};
```

Comment: @Vitaliy Welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!